# How can I refactor following activerecord query into an SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I refactor below ActiveRecord query into an SQL query?

```
where(home_team: Team.search(params, %i[name])).
  or(where(guest_team: Team.search(params, %i[name])))`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following,

```
value = Team.search(params, %i[name])
Klass.where('home_team = ? OR guest_team = ?', value, value)
```

Comment: This solution will fire two db queries instead of one.

Comment: @BhushanLodha What is your class here? `Team` itself? & are you using ranksack?

Comment: my class is `Match`

Comment: @BhushanLodha In above, where query just fire single db query and `Team.search` of course have to fire separate query

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Arel.

```rb
where(
  %i[home_team guest_team]
    .map { |field| <YourClassModel>.arel_table[field]].in(Team.search(params, %i[name])) }
    .inject(:or)
```

`<YourClassModel>.arel_table` this stuff should be moved to another function if you want to come up with my suggestion.

Another way is using `Merge` and try to break `Team.search` to the model scope and merge them with your `where` query.